# XPATH to count the occurrence of child nodes in ancestor

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to count the occurrence of the child `<title>` nodes in the `<foreword><?>` element. My problem is the parent nodes of the `<title>` element have different names, but they all have `<title>` elements.

I tried using `count(*)` but this didn't work, it comes back "0". And if I use `count(/doc/front/foreword/*/title)` it comes back with '16'. How do I count the occurrence of the `<title>` elements inside the `<foreword><?>` element?

```
    <doc>
    <front>
    <lep></lep>
    <verstat></verstat>
    <contents></contents>
    <illuslist></illuslist>
    <tablelist></tablelist>
    <foreword>
    <para0><title>para0</title></para0>
    <applicdef><title>applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <applicdef><title>applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <applicdef><title>applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <applicdef><title>applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <applicdef><title>applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <para0><title>para0</title></para0>
    <para0><title>para0</title></para0>
    <para0><title>para0</title></para0>
    <para0><title>para0</title></para0>
    </foreword>
    </front>
    </doc>
```

I numbered the `title` elements with the number that should be displayed (1.0 purpose, 2. applic...etc.

so the output would be like

```
    <para0><title>1. para0</title></para0>
    <applicdef><title>2.applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <applicdef><title>3.applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <applicdef><title>4.applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <applicdef><title>5.applicdef</title></applicdef>
    <applicdef><title>6.applicdef</title></applicdef>
```

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. Please fix it.

Comment: Are you using XPath as a part of XSLT? It seems like you're trying to modify the XML. If so you can probably accomplish this with xsl:number. If it has to be pure XPath 1.0, you can probably count preceding titles but it won't be efficient.

Comment: The XPath you suggested `count(/doc/front/foreword/*/title)` looks correct to me. Using `xmllint --xpath 'count(/doc/front/foreword/*/title)' /tmp/test.xml` yields the expected `10`. I guess you got the wrong result simply because your XML was not well-formed beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use your real life scenario, i.e. XSLT. Here is a solution by using **identity transform**.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <front>
        <lep></lep>
        <verstat></verstat>
        <contents></contents>
        <illuslist></illuslist>
        <tablelist></tablelist>
        <foreword>
            <para0>
                <title>para0</title>
            </para0>
            <applicdef>
                <title>applicdef</title>
            </applicdef>
            <applicdef>
                <title>applicdef</title>
            </applicdef>
            <applicdef>
                <title>applicdef</title>
            </applicdef>
            <applicdef>
                <title>applicdef</title>
            </applicdef>
            <applicdef>
                <title>applicdef</title>
            </applicdef>
            <para0>
                <title>para0</title>
            </para0>
            <para0>
                <title>para0</title>
            </para0>
            <para0>
                <title>para0</title>
            </para0>
            <para0>
                <title>para0</title>
            </para0>
        </foreword>
    </front>
</doc>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1,'. ', .)"/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
  <front>
    <lep/>
    <verstat/>
    <contents/>
    <illuslist/>
    <tablelist/>
    <foreword>
      <para0>
        <title>1. para0</title>
      </para0>
      <applicdef>
        <title>2. applicdef</title>
      </applicdef>
      <applicdef>
        <title>3. applicdef</title>
      </applicdef>
      <applicdef>
        <title>4. applicdef</title>
      </applicdef>
      <applicdef>
        <title>5. applicdef</title>
      </applicdef>
      <applicdef>
        <title>6. applicdef</title>
      </applicdef>
      <para0>
        <title>7. para0</title>
      </para0>
      <para0>
        <title>8. para0</title>
      </para0>
      <para0>
        <title>9. para0</title>
      </para0>
      <para0>
        <title>10. para0</title>
      </para0>
    </foreword>
  </front>
</doc>
```

Comment: This didn't work it came back with the number 10. It's giving me the sum of all titles used. Not the count in occurrence in the foreword element.

Comment: @mightymax, What is the correct number you are expecting as answer? And what's the logic behind it?

Comment: In the XML example the numbering for each title element shows the number that should be displayed. so 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @mightymax, your post is asking for "...I need to count the child nodes of the <foreword> element..." Please clarify and share the exact desired output.

Comment: @mightymax, what is wrong with the `count(/doc/front/foreword/*/title)`? It finds 10 as an answer. Please connect with me on **LinkedIn**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224212/discussion-between-mightymax-and-yitzhak-khabinsky).

Comment: It's a beautiful answer, but Arbortext Editor isn't recognizing the concat or position method.

Comment: It is strange, because concat() and position() are Xpath 1.0 functions.

Comment: When I use ancestor::*[position(  )] I don't get an error, but everything comes back as 1

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - You can't use concat as a nodetype in a XPath 1.0 path expression.

Comment: @mightymax, I completely changed the implementation by switching to XSLT. As we both now, just XPath based solution was a misnomer.